# Wanting to update a list attribute in a class without having to call an update function for every change

Tags: python, list, class, attributes

This is what I'm working with:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.z = 0
        self.w = 0
        self.data = [
            [self.x],
            [self.y],
            [self.z],
            [self.w]
        ]
```

Is it possible to update `self.data` any time another attribute changes?
I know I could just write an update function for it like:

```
def update(self):
        self.data = [
            [self.x],
            [self.y],
            [self.z],
            [self.w]
            ]
```

but I would rather not call `v.update()` 60 times/second.

I also know that I could just not use other attributes and update the list indices by doing `v.data[0] = 5`, but it would be nice to do `v.x = 5` for readability (v is an instance of Vector).

For now I'm just biting the `v.data[0] = 5` bullet...

**Edit:** Data is a list of lists for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Why not make `self.data` a `@property`? Why is it a list of lists?

Comment: No, not with integers

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Implementing `data` as a property would prevent updates from being reflected in the vector's state. (The list of lists thing is weird, though.)

Comment: I'd probably either eliminate `data` entirely (and perhaps make `Vector` a sequence type), or make `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` properties backed by `data`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you mean e.g. if `v.data[0] = 5` happens outside the class? Yes, that's true, a mutable property probably isn't a good idea as it will lead to surprising behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll try making it an `@property` and see how that goes. I'll post an update. Thanks for the quick response! As for it being a list of lists, that is for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own objects for `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` that have a custom update method. That way, when ever those attributes are updated, the change will be reflected via reference in `data`:

```
class Component:
   def __init__(self, val = 0, name='x'):
      self.val, self.name = val, name
   def update(self, new_val):
      self.val = new_val
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'{self.name}({self.val})'

class Vector:
   def __init__(self):
      self.x = Component(name='x')
      self.y = Component(name='y')
      self.z = Component(name='z')
      self.w = Component(name='w')
      self.data = [
        [self.x],
        [self.y],
        [self.z],
        [self.w]
      ]

v = Vector()
print('before update: ', v.data)
v.x.update(100)
v.y.update(200)
v.z.update(300)
v.w.update(400)
print('after update: ', v.data)
```

Output:

```
before update:  [[x(0)], [y(0)], [z(0)], [w(0)]]
after update:  [[x(100)], [y(200)], [z(300)], [w(400)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single place to store the data and make the x,y,z,w peoperties that read and write self.data at their respective indexes:

```
class Vector:
    
    def dataProperty(i):
        def getter(obj): return obj.data[i][0]
        def setter(obj,value): obj.data[i][0] = value
        return property(getter,setter)

    x,y,z,w = map(dataProperty,range(4))
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [[0] for _ in range(4)]
```

output:

```
v = Vector()
v.x = 123
v.z = 456

print(v.data) # [[123], [0], [456], [0]]

v.data[0][0] += 876

print(v.x) # 999
```